# Scraping iTunes Charts using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am doing the following tutorial on using Scrapy to scrape iTunes charts.
http://davidwalsh.name/python-scrape

The tutorial is slightly outdated, in that some of the syntaxes used have been deprecated in the current version of Scrapy (e.g. HtmlXPathSelector, BaseSpider..) - I have been working on completing the tutorial with the current version of Scrapy, but to no success.

If anyone knows what I'm doing incorrectly, would love to understand what I need to work on.

items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class AppItem(Item):
    app_name = Field()
    category = Field()
    appstore_link = Field()
    img_src = Field()
```

apple_spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from apple.items import AppItem

class AppleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "apple"
    allowed_domains = ["apple.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.apple.com/itunes/charts/free-apps/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        apps = response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/section/ul/li')
        count = 0
        items = []

        for app in apps:

            item = AppItem()
            item['app_name'] = app.select('//h3/a/text()')[count].extract()
            item['appstore_link'] = app.select('//h3/a/@href')[count].extract()
            item['category'] = app.select('//h4/a/text()')[count].extract()
            item['img_src'] = app.select('//a/img/@src')[count].extract()

            items.append(item)
            count += 1

        return items
```

This is my console message after running `scrapy crawl apple`:

```
2015-02-10 13:38:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: apple)
2015-02-10 13:38:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, django
2015-02-10 13:38:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'apple.spiders', '
SPIDER_MODULES': ['apple.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'apple'}
2015-02-10 13:38:12-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, We
bService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, Download
TimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddle
ware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, D
ownloaderStats
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMidd
leware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [apple] INFO: Spider opened
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [apple] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items
/min)
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [apple] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.apple.com/itunes/charts/free-a
pps/> (referer: None)
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [apple] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [apple] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 236,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 13148,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 10, 18, 38, 13, 271000),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 10, 18, 38, 13, 240000)}
2015-02-10 13:38:13-0500 [apple] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Thanks in advance for any help/advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reading the technical part: make sure you are not violating the `iTunes` terms of use.

All of the problems you have are inside the `parse()` callback:

- the main xpath is not correct (there is no `ul` element directly under the `section`)
- instead of `response.selector` you can directly use `response`
- the xpath expressions in the loop should be context-specific

The fixed version:

```
def parse(self, response):
    apps = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/section//ul/li')

    for app in apps:
        item = AppItem()
        item['app_name'] = app.xpath('.//h3/a/text()').extract()
        item['appstore_link'] = app.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').extract()
        item['category'] = app.xpath('.//h4/a/text()').extract()
        item['img_src'] = app.xpath('.//a/img/@src').extract()

        yield item
```

Comment: Thank you alecxe! The correction makes sense, but can you just briefly explain why the `count` variable is excluded in your revision of the code? How did this all get accomplished without the loop counter (or better put, what purpose did that loop counter serve to begin with?).

Comment: @ploo sure, the key thing to understand is that a `response` is basically a selector and `app` is also a selector of an `li` element. We don't need a loop index or count variable here just because the `app` variable on every iteration is already a specific `li` element where we can search for using `xpath()`. I'm terrible at explaining things, but hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think I get it - thanks again for the prompt response, very helpful! Cheers